# Can I set composer file structure name for load psr4?

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

In first place, sorry for my english and thanks for help me.

I am trying to add Composer psr-4 functionability to own project. But I have a problem, I have a lot of classes files with ".class.php" name style. I want to know if i can say to composer that he need find these files, not only "myclass.php", i need find "myclass.class.php"

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer. but really this is not a code problem, is just that i have various files with this kind of names: "Database.class.php", "Controller.class.php", "View.class.php" "Model.class.php" and composer does not recognize these classes. It only check files like "View.php" and "Database.php" [without the ".class" extension]. Then, i just want to know if i can do something for composer accept this namefile format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach here is to simply rename those files. OS X has a great [batch rename](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/batch-rename-files-os-x-yosemite/) feature now.

There is no purpose having `.class` in there, and if it's causing trouble for you then might as well yank em out.

That said, there are plenty of ways to [autoload in Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) that have nothing to do with PSR-4. Maybe take a look at classmap.